# Как сделать, чтобы анимация не возвращалась после выполнения

Tags: java, android, xml, анимация

У нас есть определенная позиция `TextView`. Когда я применяю для него анимацию, после завершения, он отправляется на свое прошлое место. Как сделать так, чтобы после анимации он остался в таком же положении, когда закончилась анимация.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:duration="2000">
<translate
   android:fromXDelta="-200"
   android:toXDelta="0">
</translate>
</set>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установи `fillAfter="true"` и после выполнения анимации состояние анимируемого объекта не сброситься в исходное. По умолчанию этот флаг имеет значение `false`.